# Make three.js object invisible

Tags: three.js, gsap

I have used the following code to create a mesh object

```
var defaultPartGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.5, 0.5, 0.5);
var defaultPartMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff0000, wireframe: false});
default = new THREE.Mesh(defaultPartGeometry, defaultPartMaterial); 
default.position.set(0,0.25,0); 
scene.add(default)
```

How can I make this invisible? Setting the `opacity` for this object to `null` did not work.

I address the object by its `ID` and then try to set the `opacity` (I also have tried to address the material: `object.material`).

```
object = SceneService.scene.getObjectByName(ID);
tweens.push(tl.to(object, 2, { opacity: 0 }, e.time));
```

Tween the position is working:

```
tweens.push(tl.to(object.position, 2, { x: target.X, z: target.Y }, e.time));
```

**EDIT:**

```
object = SceneService.scene.getObjectByName(e.id);
object.transparent = true;
tweens.push(tl.to(object.position, 2, { x: target.X, z: target.Y }), e.time);
tweens.push(tl.to(object, 2, { opacity: 0 }), e.time);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have forgotten the `transparent` property :

```
object.material.transparent = true ;
TweenMax.to( object.material, duration, { opacity : 0 } );
```

Comment: yes, I know this, but I want to combine that with tweenmax because I want to have a fade in opacity, Hope you can understand.

Comment: thanks! I have edited,  too, But the code is not working again.

Comment: one question: any idea why setting the opacity for the material of one object to 0 adress all other objects with this material? can I only change the visibility of the material on only one object?

Comment: What you are asking is called _inheritance_, it is a general question about _object-oriented programmation_ in javascript. But to answer briefly if you apply the same material to many objects and modify its `opacity`, it will do that for all objects sharing this material. You have to create another material for those objects if you want them not to have the same behavior.

Comment: any idea how this works with collada models? I need traverse function?

Comment: yep. Check the threejs examples.

Comment: I don't find any example where they use tweenMax and opacity?

Comment: There is not, but with the [threejs examples](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_loader_collada), this answer and  more [on SO about collada loader](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bthree.js%5D+collada) you should have enough to code that. If you still can't, ask another question.

Comment: ok, thanks, i look if I can find a solution :-) Have a nice day!